# How to copy from a particular cell and paste it in a another range using excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel where i have defined "CTPT" in the column A. I am successful in fetching the cell address of the "CTPT" using the code :

```
With .Range("A1:A10000")
Set cF = .Find(what:="CTPT", _
    lookat:=xlPart, searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

num = cF.Address ' Here i get the cell address $A$14
```

[image]

Now the task which i am struggling is that i want to copy from all the data in Control Power Transformers (Here its from A13 till B18), select the particular range with the help of "CTPT" cell address.

I tried with the below code but it copied columns B,C and D without selecting column A.

```
WsEPC.Range(cF.Offset(-1, 3), cF.Offset(2, 1).End(xlDown)).Copy
```

Can any one help me in achieving it. Any help is Appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
WsEPC.Range(cF.Offset(-1, 0), cF.Offset(3, 3)).Copy
```

Comment: No its selecting only 3rd column.